# How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to Russian?

Tags: произношение

I am working on an art project that I would like to collect the hundreds of different transliterations of 「中文」 zhōng wén in Mandarin Chinese. (Pronunciation available here: [https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/中文](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87))

How can I transliterate zhōng wén in Russian? (For example, "zhong wen" would be the closest pronunciation in English.)

thank you

Comment: Palladius' system would have it as *чжунвэнь*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the end of the 19th century, the traditional transliteration system of rendering Chinese words in the Russian Cyrillic alphabet is the so-called [Palladius system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillization_of_Chinese) named after Pyotr Ivanovich Kafarov (Пётр Ива́нович Кафа́ров), a Russian sinologist and monk who spent thirty years in China and was also known by his monastic name Palladius (Паллáдий). Actually, every Chinese syllable possible has a corresponding Palladius system equivalent, that Wikipedia article has the chart of the Pinyin ­– Cyrillic Palladius correspondences.

But there is an easier way to do the transliteration, there in an [online converter](http://palladius.ru/), you enter either the Chinese characters or Pinyin there, press the "Convert" (Перевести) button, and you get it in Cyrillic Palladius. As for your word,「中文」zhōng wén, it is `чжунвэнь`.